# Html css how to fit image in box?

Tags: html, css

I am showing simple image in my div. Problem is its not showing perfectly in box i need to cover the whole div here is my code

```
.card-background{
  background-image: url("../../../assets/imgs/back-blank.png");
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 2%;
  height: 180px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

}

<div class="card-background">
</div>
```

[image]

Image width is 1200 px which is enough to cover the div. I need to show the image fit in the div

Also i i use background-size: cover; its cropping the image in div here is the image 
[image]

Comment: but where do you add `.card-background` class?

Comment: @FedeSc sorry now i have added

Comment: use `background-size: cover;` instead of *contain*

Comment: @Red try this but the border of image is cropping mean the logo in image in end is cropping in div

Answer (score 0):

use 
`background-position: center;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.card-background{
  background-image: url("../../../assets/imgs/back-blank.png");
      border-radius: 10px;
      margin-top: 2%;
      height: 180px;
      background-size: cover;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center;
    }
```